# How toggle alacritty terminal colorscheme with a keystroke?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, colors

There is an explanation on how to do that in a [section](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/wiki/Color-schemes#multiple-schemes) in the alacritty's git-hub wiki, but I didn't get that. I experimented with it for example for solarized's light and dark version, but I failed.

Please show me how can I have **multiple color-schemes** at hand and how **toggle/switch** among them, preferably via **key-strokes**.

[I'm not sure this is the right place for this question, so let me know :)]

**Edit:** I fixed multiple *schemes*, according to the wiki. My mistake was I forgot to change the `color` keyword to a name that I then refer to. its like:

```
# XTerm's color-schemes
schemes:
    xterm_light: &light
           # Default colors
           primary:
             background: '#ffffff'
             foreground: '#000000'
           # Normal colors
           normal:
             black:   '#000000'
             red:     '#cd0000'
             green:   '#00cd00'
             yellow:  '#cdcd00'
             blue:    '#0000ee'
             magenta: '#cd00cd'
             cyan:    '#00adad'
             white:   '#c5c5c5'

           # Bright colors
           bright:
             black:   '#7f7f7f'
             red:     '#ff0000'
             green:   '#00ff00'
             yellow:  '#ffff00'
             blue:    '#5c5cff'
             magenta: '#ff00ff'
             cyan:    '#00fff             
             white:   '#ffffff'

    xterm_dark: &dark
           # Default colors
           primary:
             background: '#000000'
             foreground: '#ffffff'
           # Normal colors
           normal:
             black:   '#000000'
             red:     '#cd0000'
             green:   '#00cd00'
             yellow:  '#cdcd00'
             blue:    '#0050cc'
             magenta: '#cd00cd'
             cyan:    '#00adad'
             white:   '#e5e5e5'

           # Bright colors
           bright:
             black:   '#7f7f7f'
             red:     '#ff0000'
             green:   '#00ff00'
             yellow:  '#ffff00'
             blue:    '#5c5cff'
             magenta: '#ff00ff'
             cyan:    '#00ffff'
             white:   '#ffffff'

colors: *dark
# colors: *light
```

In this case I need to manually change the config in order to change the color-scheme. It's not the worst thing, but it would be nice to change it by keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [I'm not sure this is the right place for this question, so let me
> know :)]

Since this is my first answer here, I don't know if this is the right place for the question :-). But, I had the same problem a little while back and fixed it with the following python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import yaml
import os
import re


CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "alacritty.yml"
CONFIG_FILE_DIR = os.path.expanduser("~/.config/alacritty/")
CONFIG_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(CONFIG_FILE_DIR, CONFIG_FILE_NAME)

COLOR_SCHEME_LINE_SEARCH = "colors: \*(\S+)"
COLOR_SCHEME_LINE_TEMPLATE = "colors: *{}\n"

with open(CONFIG_FILE_PATH, "r") as config_file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(config_file)
    config_file.seek(0)
    lines = config_file.readlines()

colors_line_index = -1
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    match = re.search(COLOR_SCHEME_LINE_SEARCH, line)
    if match is not None:
        current_color_scheme = match.group(1)
        colors_line_index = i

available_color_schemes = list(config["schemes"].keys())

color_scheme_index = available_color_schemes.index(current_color_scheme)
color_scheme_index = \
    (color_scheme_index + 1) % len(available_color_schemes)

lines[colors_line_index] = COLOR_SCHEME_LINE_TEMPLATE.format(
    available_color_schemes[color_scheme_index])

with open(CONFIG_FILE_PATH, "w") as config_file:
    for line in lines:
        config_file.write(line)
```

Depending on where your alacritty config file is, you might have to adjust the CONFIG_FILE_NAME and the CONFIG_FILE_DIR. For the script to work it is important that you name the anchors of the color schemes exactly the same as the color schemes themselfs, e.g.:

```
schemes:
  example_color_scheme: &example_color_schme
    primary:
        ...
    normal:
        ...
    bright:
        ...
```

Other than that the Python package **pyyaml** has to be installed on your system, the script has to be made executable by the user, and the script must be reachable from the user's PATH.

Additionally I put the following in my alacritty config file:

```
key_bindings:
  - { key: F, mods: Control, command: {program: "set_colorscheme.py"} }
```

This way, I can cycle through my color schems by pressing <CTRL-F>.

You can check it out the scipt in my [dotfiles on github](https://github.com/schuam/.dotfiles/tree/master/.config/alacritty).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I switched to st because of some bugs in alacritty 4.3 (i use debian), so I haven't tested your script yet. however, I accept this answer, because I assume this works for you. I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. It indeed works for me.

Comment: For me key binding command structure _had_ to invoke the script either through `python` executable or through `sh`. For example (without shebang, works slightly faster): `program: "<absolute_path_to_python>", args: [ "<path_to_script_relative_to_alacritty_yml>" ]`, or (still requires absolute path to Python, but in shebang): `program: "/bin/sh", args: [ "-c", "~/bin/cycle_alacritty_colors.py" ]`.

Comment: I placed the script in a directory that's in my PATH (specifically /usr/local/bin/). Therefore I didn't need the absolute path to the script. The shebang line takes care of running the script in python.
I assume that you're right, that calling python directly might be a little faster, but when I invoke the keybinding to change the color, it seems to change pretty instantaneously. That's good enough for me :-).